# Implementing Complex numbers into a collection and operations on it

Tags: java

I have a task for my IT class, i should implement a collection class with complex numbers elements and should define some operations based on this collection such as intersection, union, complements and cartesian product.

In my programm i defined the collection class(multime) where i think to define my two collections to do operations based on them.

Then i defined the Complex Numbers class (nrComplex) which helps me to build complex numbers.

In my Main class i gave values for complex numbers, it should be better if i input them from keyboard but it's ok even with this.

Now my question is: how i should introduce the complex numbers into collections, for example if i define A and B collections where A={a,b,c,d} and B={e,f,g}, because the operations must be done on collections not on specific complex number.

I'm new at java and i search on google to solve every problem, so my code should be weired for some good programmers.

Here is my code:

```
package multime;
/**
*
* @author Dragosh
 */

public class Multime { 

    public static void main (String args[]) {
        try {
            Multime obj = new Multime();
            obj.run (args);
        }
        catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace(); 
        }
    }

    public void run (String args[]) throws Exception {
        NumarComplex a = new NumarComplex();
        a.setReal(1);// This one should be in first collection A
        a.setImaginar(2);// This one should be in first collection A
        b.setReal(3);// This one should be in second collection B
        b.setImaginar(5);// This one should be in second collection B
    }

    class NumarComplex {

        private float re, im;

        public float getReal() {
            return re;
        }

        public void setReal(float re) {
            this.re = re;
        }

        public float getImaginar() {
            return im;
        }

        public void setImaginar(float im) {
            this.im = im;
        }
    }   
}
```

Comment: Have you looked at java `Collections` framework classes, like `List` and `Set`? Also a tip: use double over float. Or even BigDecimal

Comment: Also, you're declaring `NumarComplex a`, but there's not equivalent declaration for `b`.

Comment: Yeah, in my programm i declared it, forgot to declare here

Answer (score 0):

You have defined the `NumarComplex` object you want to put in the collection, but you haven't actually got a collection to hold these at the moment. I guess that is what you are asking for help with.

You could do this by extending the `AbstractCollection` defined in `java.util`

This could be done like so using the `NumarComplex` class you have already written:

```
class ComplexNumberCollection extends AbstractCollection<NumarComplex> {

    @Override
    public Iterator<NumarComplex> iterator() {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        return null;
    }

    @Override
    public int size() {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        return 0;
    }

}
```

Then you can write the other methods you have been asked to implemented like `intersection`, `union` etc. You may also want to add some constructors to this class. See [section 5 here](http://www.ibm.com/developerworks/java/library/j-5things2/) for some more information.